# (Powershell) new-object cmdlet doesn't return anything using [CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection]

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script in which I have to create several temporary files. I stumbled upon a .net class that sounds very useful to manage this task:[System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection].

However for some strange reason I'm not able to create an object.
Here's what I've tried to do:

```
$a = new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\"
```

$a is empty after this call.

However if I do this:

```
(new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\").tempdir
```

It returns:

```
C:\folder1\
```

This means an object has been created. I just seem to be unable to save it into a variable! Does anybody have any idea why that is?

Another strange thing:

```
new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\" | gm
```

Returns:

```
Name          MemberType Definition                                                                                         
----          ---------- ----------                                                                                         
AddExtension  Method     string AddExtension(string fileExtension), string 
...
```

However this returns an exception (Get-Member : No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.) :

```
(new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\") | gm
```

I'm sorry for articulating this problem so badly, I don't know how to explain it better.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: it's not empty.

How are you verifying that $a is empty?  I think if you'll actually try just using it, it will work fine:

```
PS> $a = New-Object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\"
PS> $a.TempDir
C:\folder1\
PS> $a.AddFile("test1.txt",$false)
PS> $a.AddFile("test2.txt",$false)
PS> $a
C:\Users\Jaykul\AppData\Local\Temp\test2.txt
C:\Users\Jaykul\AppData\Local\Temp\test1.txt
PS>
```

In a nutshell, the problem you're having is that PowerShell unrolls collections (that is, it outputs the CONTENTS of the collection) when you send them through the pipeline. That's because otherwise, when you type:

```
PS> $a = Get-ChildItem
PS> $a
```

You would just see that it's an array: `System.Object[]` ...

In that sort of situation, you almost always want to see the *contents* of the array. As an aside: this is a great example of how PowerShell is ***first** a shell language*, and then a scripting language: it prioritizes the right behavior for a shell.

Anyway, there are a few exceptions for that unrolling of enumerable collections (strings are IEnumerable, but are not unrolled), and in fact, I think `New-Object ... |` is special-cased which is why it worked to pipe New-Object to Get-Member at all. Of course, once you wrapped it in parenthesis, you created a sub-expression which is parsed separately, so when you write:

```
(new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\") | gm
```

You basically have two pipelines, and the special treatment of New-Object vanishes, your collection is unrolled, and it's contents (nothing, because it's empty) are passed down the pipeline.

You can avoid this by using the unary comma operator:

```
$a = new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\"
,$a | gm
```

or 
    ,(new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\") | gm

or by passing it to the -InputObject parameter directly instead of through the pipeline.

```
$a = new-object CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection -argumentlist "C:\folder1\"
gm -InputObject $a
```

However, when you're using a fancy collection, and you want to see the **values** of the properties of the collection object itself, you'll probably need to do both:

```
PS> ft -in (,$a)

    Count TempDir            BasePath                    KeepFiles SyncRoot               IsSynchronized
    ----- -------            --------                    --------- --------               --------------
        3 C:\folder1\        C:\folder1\t22jmahj             False                                 False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very useful. I tried to verify that $a is empty by comparing it with $null, which returned nothing. That confused me even more.